# How to only get where: True?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

Stuck in a little problem ...

Basically I have a list of bonuses at the front-end, with checkboxes where user can select which type of bonus to display.

The bonus db table has a boolean field set to true or false. Problem is when I query the Bonus table I get results when the choices are negative.

I want to only get items where the variable/choice is true. And bonuses(where: { welcome_bonus: $welcomeBonus }) will return results if welcome_bonus is false.  I only want to get any results if $welcomeBonus or any of the other variables is "true".

Is it possible to accomplish that in the Query or do I need to filter the results somehow afterwards? There must be a better way than this mess ...

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const BONUSES_QUERY = gql`
  query bonuses(
    $welcomeBonus: Boolean
    $depositBonus: Boolean
    $monthlyBonus: Boolean
    $weeklyBonus: Boolean
    $slotsBonus: Boolean
    $noDepositBonus: Boolean
  ) {
    welcomeBonuses: bonuses(where: { welcome_bonus: $welcomeBonus }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }

    depositBonuses: bonuses(where: { deposit_bonus: $depositBonus }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }

    monthlyBonuses: bonuses(where: { monthly_bonus: $monthlyBonus }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }

    weeklyBonuses: bonuses(where: { weekly_bonus: $weeklyBonus }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }

    slotsBonuses: bonuses(where: { slots_bonus: $slotsBonus }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }

    noDepositBonuses: bonuses(where: { nodeposit_bonus: $noDepositBonus }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }
  }
  fragment BonusParts on Bonuses {
    id
    name
    slug
    welcome_bonus
    deposit_bonus
    monthly_bonus
    weekly_bonus
    slots_bonus
    nodeposit_bonus
  }
`;

export default BONUSES_QUERY;
```

Comment: simply `bonuses(where: { welcome_bonus: $welcomeBonus deposit_bonus: $depositBonus ...... }) {
      ...BonusParts
    }
` ? or even more simply pass one `$where` 'filtering object' arg/variable [prepared in FE]

Comment: Actually I tried that one :), but unfortunately the problem remains... Since $depositBonus could be set to false, and then it will get the depositbonuses set to false. I only want to get them if they are set to true. Still in hope but puzzled, there must be a simple solution to it.

Comment: this "arg only true interpretation" belongs to your business logic, in resolver, simply filter only true values